# How to scrape description field from Jira in ruby?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

On my current project ,Wanted to scrape the description field. Am using nokogiri for scraping.

can anybody have a look and let me know how to overcome this ?

```or-tag-here
<div class='module toggle-wrap' id='descriptionmodule'>
   <div id='descriptionmodule_heading' class='mod-header'>
      <h3 class='toggle-title'>Description</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

trying like this -

```
Description = details.at_css("descriptionmodule[@id='description-val']").text.strip
```

Comment: what is your problem? any error or what ? Give the HTML part also

Comment: not getting the description as listed in the description value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **CSS** rule wasn't correct. Try as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<html)
<div class='module toggle-wrap' id='descriptionmodule'>
   <div id='descriptionmodule_heading' class='mod-header'>
      <h3 class='toggle-title'>Description</h3>
   </div>
</div>
html

doc.at_css("#descriptionmodule #descriptionmodule_heading > h3").text.strip
# => "Description"
```

Look at the documentation :

[`ID Selector (“#id”)`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) : Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

[`Child Selector (“parent > child”)`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) : Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and made changes but now am getting like this :"Description: Description" .It's not scraping the value.code -description = details.at_css("#descriptionmodule #descriptionmodule_heading > h3").text.strip

Comment: @user2694406 I didn't get your point. Edit your question itself.

Comment: Fixed used like -description = details.at_css("#descriptionmodule #description-val").text.strip

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and able to scrape description properly

```
description = details.at_css("#descriptionmodule #description-val").text.strip
```